# Custom Post Type Metabox - Not Saving

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I've added a custom post type, which is working great; I've also added two metaboxes, which appear to work well, but the content in them always disappears after a few minutes.

If anyone could help out on this I would be eternally grateful, S.

//meta box code//

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_custom_metabox' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_custom_details' );

function add_custom_metabox() {
    add_meta_box( 'custom-metabox', __( 'Product Description &amp; Ingredients' ), 'descr_custom_metabox', 'sorbets', 'normal', 'low' );
}

function descr_custom_metabox() {
    global $post;
    $proddescr = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'proddescr', true );
    $ingredients = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ingredients', true );
    ?>
    <p><label for="proddescr">Product Description:<br />
        <textarea id="proddescr" name="proddescr" style="margin:0;height:7em;width:98%;" cols="45" rows="4"><?php if( $proddescr ) { echo $proddescr; } ?></textarea></label></p>
    <p><label for="ingredients">Ingredients:<br />
        <textarea id="ingredients" name="ingredients" style="margin:0;height:7em;width:98%;" cols="45" rows="4"><?php if( $ingredients ) { echo $ingredients; } ?></textarea></label></p>
<?php
}

function save_custom_details( $post_ID ) {
    global $post;   
    if( $_POST ) {
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'proddescr', $_POST['proddescr'] );
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ingredients', $_POST['ingredients'] );
    }
}

function get_descr_ingred_box() {
    global $post;

    $proddescr = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'proddescr', true );
    $ingredients = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ingredients', true );

    return array( $proddescr, $ingredients );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check for `autosave` and avoid that , also check if you are in the right post type as `save_post` works on all posts:

```
function save_custom_details( $post_id ) {
    global $post;   
    //skip auto save
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    //check for you post type only
    if( $post->post_type == "sorbets" ) {
        if( isset($_POST['proddescr']) ) { update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'proddescr', $_POST['proddescr'] );}
        if( isset($_POST['ingredients']) ) { update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ingredients', $_POST['ingredients'] );}

    }
}
```

WOW you guys are fast :)

Comment: WHOOPS! Yes, this is an important step, but the when this script is run the global $post hasn't been set up yet, that is why $post_ID is passed into the function, you do need to use $post_ID instead of getting global $post and using $post->ID.

Comment: @Drew Gourley: Not quite true, when `save_post` is fired global $post is set!. and some times you need more the the post ID so globalization of $post is needed.

Comment: Many thanks to you both - seems to be working great now!

Comment: @Bainternet: Just checked and it seems it is indeed set, but I've had similar trouble with it in the past, strange...I just figured it hadn't been set when save_post is fired on the next request. The function I wrote was much more simple and I didn't have to check for the post type. Yup, we need global $post here.

Comment: You're referencing 3 different post ID variables in that sample, could you not just use the ID that's passed from the hook throughout the code? (like Drew has in his answer)..

Comment: @t31os: referencing 3 different post ID was a typo, i meant only two, and yes you could do that with that single variable passed by $post_id, but like said in the second comment "some times you need more then the post ID".

Comment: Bainternet, I have a similar problem http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28341/custom-post-type-not-saving, I've tried your solution but I doesn't seem to work, the data still disappears after 10 minutes. Would you be able to help me out?

Comment: @Bainternet: No need to return `$post_id` when skipping because of autosave. You can just do `return;` in functions hooked to actions.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I see from what you are doing here and the function I use is that you are relying on global $post to set up the ID, this may be what is breaking this for you.

You'll notice the variable $post_ID is already being passed into this function:

```
function save_custom_details( $post_ID ) {
    global $post;   
    if( $_POST ) {
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'proddescr', $_POST['proddescr'] );
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ingredients', $_POST['ingredients'] );
    }
}
```

I would suggest changing it to this:

```
function save_custom_details( $post_ID ) {
    if( isset($_POST) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_ID, 'proddescr', $_POST['proddescr'] );
        update_post_meta( $post_ID, 'ingredients', $_POST['ingredients'] );
    }
}
```

I also switched your condtion from ( $_POST ) to ( isset($_POST) ), it is a more reliable way of getting an answer for an IF statement. Let me know if this helps. If not, I'll dig into it a little further.